# expanding exponential of inverse

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Expand $(1-3x)^{-1}$ and find the greatest coefficient. Just wondering if there would be need to factorise before proceeding just as in the case of $(2-3x)^{-3}$. Response will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by expanding? Taylor Series?

Comment: If you look for the partial fraction expansion, I'm afraid you cannot expand $\frac{1}{1-3x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) OR Infinite Geometric Series

$$(1-3x)^{-1}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty(3x)^r$$  for $|3x|<1$

So, the coefficient of $r$th term $T_r=3^r$

$$\implies\dfrac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}=3$$

Clearly, the coefficient are ever increasing.